# Convert Mathematical formula to HTML

Tags: c#, excel-import

i want to convert mathematics formulas as HTML text while reading from excel file.
my problem is that formula are coming as a simple text on server.

here is a example

[image: below is my excel cell data]

when i am reading the excel file it is coming like "log10 10= 1" unable to recognize subscript or any other mathematical sign.

Comment: You'd have to take that text and transform it (pull out operators, etc) to perform operations on it, besides that it's not clear what you expect

Comment: You want parse logxY into its components, and potentially other math formulas, that are all coming as plaintext? This is going to be very difficult, considering x and Y could be a variety of character lengths. Is there any way you can get the formatted cell?

Comment: How do you read the excel document in your code? Do you use 3rd party librarşes like aspose?

Comment: already posted server side code ,how i am  reading  the file @AbdullahNehir

Comment: it like a text editor where you can enter any things and it convert into html markup and that text  only inserted into DB. i want to insert same things but in bulk using excel .